# Printing ASCII art next to each other

Tags: python-3.x, ascii, ascii-art

I'm trying to create a Yahtzee game for one person, using random numbers as dice etc etc

I have done that but I want to 'pretty' up the game, so instead of outputting five random integers next to each other I want to use ASCII dice next to each other.

This is my current attempt at testing this

```
def DiceFive():
    print ("-----")
    print ("|o o|")
    print ("| o |")
    print ("|o o|")
    print ("-----", end="")

def DiceSix():
    print ("-----")
    print ("|o o|")
    print ("|o o|")
    print ("|o o|")
    print ("-----", end="")

DiceSix()
DiceFive()
```

However this outputs strangely,

```
-----
|o o|
|o o|
|o o|
----------
|o o|
| o |
|o o|
-----
```

My aim is for it to look like this

```
----- -----
|o o| |o o|
|o o| | o |
|o o| |o o|
----- -----
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the dice into a list of tuples which contain the rows (strings) of the dice. Then you can iterate over the height of the dice (5 in this case), so you start at index 0, and then iterate over the rolled dice and print the first row of the first die, then the first row of the second die and so on.

```
DICE = [
    ("-----",
     "|   |",
     "| o |",
     "|   |",
     "-----",),
    ("-----",
     "|o  |",
     "|   |",
     "|  o|",
     "-----",),  # etc.
    ]


rolled_dice = (1, 2)

for i in range(5):  # 5 is the height of the die.
    for die in rolled_dice:
        # Now get the corresponding die in the DICE list
        # and print its first line, then the first line of
        # the next die and so on.
        print(DICE[die-1][i], end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: It would also be possible to use the zip function to zip the strings together, but in this case I think it's easier to just use the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
five = """-----
|o o|
| o |
|o o|
-----""".split("\n")

six = """-----
|o o|
|o o|
|o o|
-----""".split("\n")


for row in zip(six, five):
    print(row[0] + " " + row[1])
```

Output:

```
----- -----
|o o| |o o|
|o o| | o |
|o o| |o o|
----- -----
```

Answer (score 0):

The following game was adapted from a Python 2.5 program published about five years ago. It is old and may contain bugs but demonstrates one possibility for displaying your cards in an orderly manner on the screen. Lines 397 - 470 create the cards that can be displayed. The functions `show_pot`, `show_captured_cards`, `show_playing_cards`, and `show_pot_before_play` are responsible for printing the cards to the screen.

The following version of the game has been cleaned up a bit more and may be a little easier to follow. The primary logic for the game is implemented in the `main` function starting at line 476. The game's logic has been split up into functions, and a few named tuples were added as well. Creating dice to display on the screen should not be too difficult to accomplish with the various examples provided in the game shown below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578369-war-game-version-5/

"""Support module for array and matrix use.

This module provides two classes that emulate one and two
dimensional lists with fixed sizes but mutable internals."""

__all__ = ['Array', 'Matrix']
__version__ = '1.2'

import collections
import random


class Array(object):
    """array(length) -> new array
    array(length, value) -> initialized from value"""

    def __init__(self, length, value=None):
        """x.__init__(...) initializes x"""
        self.__data = list(range(length))
        for index in range(length):
            self.__data[index] = value

    def __repr__(self):
        """x.__repr__() <==> repr(x)"""
        return repr(self.__data)

    def __len__(self):
        """x.__len__() <==> len(x)"""
        return len(self.__data)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """x.__getitem__(y) <==> x[y]"""
        return self.__data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """x.__setitem__(i, y) <==> x[i]=y"""
        self.__data[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        """x.__delitem__(y) <==> del x[y]"""
        self.__data[key] = None

    def __iter__(self):
        """x.__iter__() <==> iter(x)"""
        return iter(self.__data)

    def __contains__(self, value):
        """x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x"""
        return value in self.__data


class Matrix(object):
    """matrix(rows, columns) -> new matrix
    matrix(rows, columns, value) -> initialized from value"""

    def __init__(self, rows, columns, value=None):
        """x.__init__(...) initializes x"""
        self.__data = Array(rows)
        for index in range(rows):
            self.__data[index] = Array(columns, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        """x.__repr__() <==> repr(x)"""
        return repr(self.__data)

    def __len__(self):
        """x.__len__() <==> len(x)"""
        return len(self.__data)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """x.__getitem__(y) <==> x[y]"""
        return self.__data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """x.__setitem__(i, y) <==> x[i]=y"""
        self.__data[key] = Array(len(self.__data[key]), value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        """x.__delitem__(y) <==> del x[y]"""
        self.__data[key] = Array(len(self.__data[key]))

    def __iter__(self):
        """x.__iter__() <==> iter(x)"""
        return iter(self.__data)

    def __contains__(self, value):
        """x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x"""
        for item in self.__data:
            if value in item:
                return True
        return False


class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, value=None):
        self.__assert_type((int, rows), (int, columns))
        if value:
            self.__assert_type((str, value))
            self.__data = Matrix(rows, columns, value[0])
        else:
            self.__data = Matrix(rows, columns, ' ')
        self.__visible = True
        self.__x = 0
        self.__y = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__data)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([''.join(row) for row in self.__data])

    def size(self):
        """Return a tuple of matrix's size."""
        return len(self.__data), len(self.__data[0])

    def access(self, row, column, length=None):
        """Get a string of length from row and column."""
        self.__assert_type((int, row), (int, column))
        if length:
            self.__assert_type((int, length))
        else:
            length = 1
        string = ''
        for index in range(length):
            try:
                string += self.__data[row][column + index]
            except IndexError:
                pass
        return string

    def mutate(self, row, column, value):
        """Write a character or string where told."""
        self.__assert_type((int, row), (int, column), (str, value))
        for index in range(len(value)):
            try:
                self.__data[row][column + index] = value[index]
            except IndexError:
                pass
        return self

    def set_row(self, row, value=None):
        """Set or clear a row to one character."""
        self.__assert_type((int, row))
        if value:
            self.__assert_type((str, value))
            self.__data[row] = value[0]
        else:
            self.__data[row] = ' '
        return self

    def set_column(self, column, value=None):
        """Set or clear a column to one character."""
        self.__assert_type((int, column))
        if value:
            self.__assert_type((str, value))
        else:
            value = ' '
        for row in self.__data:
            row[column] = value[0]
        return self

    def visible(self, value=None):
        """Get or set visible."""
        if value is None:
            return self.__visible
        else:
            self.__assert_type((bool, value))
            self.__visible = value
            return self

    def x(self, value=None):
        """Get or set x."""
        if value is None:
            return self.__x
        else:
            self.__assert_type((int, value))
            self.__x = value
            return self

    def y(self, value=None):
        """Get or set y."""
        if value is None:
            return self.__y
        else:
            self.__assert_type((int, value))
            self.__y = value
            return self

    def project(self, value):
        """Copy value to self with offset."""
        for row in range(value.size()[0]):
            for column in range(value.size()[1]):
                try:
                    self.__data[value.y() + row][value.x() + column] = \
                        value.__data[row][column]
                except IndexError:
                    pass
        return self

    def page(self):
        """Casting statement."""
        return self

    def link(self, value):
        """Use and share value's __data."""
        if value.__class__ is Page:
            self.__data = value.__data
            return self
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def unlink(self):
        """Create a new matrix."""
        temp = Matrix(len(self.__data), len(self.__data[0]))
        # Copy all of the data to the new matrix.
        for row in range(len(self.__data)):
            for column in range(len(self.__data[0])):
                temp[row][column] = self.__data[row][column]
        # Finish the conversion.
        self.__data = temp
        # Allow more work to be done.
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def __assert_type(*tuples):
        for types, objects in tuples:
            if type(objects) is not types:
                raise TypeError


class Window(object):
    def __init__(self, height, width, border=None, background=None):
        self.__assert_type((int, height), (int, width))
        if border:
            self.__assert_type((str, border))
            self.__border = border[0]
        else:
            self.__border = ''
        if background:
            self.__assert_type((str, background))
            self.__background = background[0]
        else:
            self.__background = ' '
        self.__height = height
        self.__width = width
        self.__page = Page(0, 0)
        self.__list = list()
        self.__refresh()

    def __repr__(self):
        self.__refresh()
        return repr(self.__page)

    def __str__(self):
        self.__refresh()
        return str(self.__page)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__list)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.__assert_type((int, key))
        return self.__list[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__assert_type((int, key))
        if value.__class__ is Page or value.__class__ is Window:
            self.__list[key] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.__assert_type((int, key))
        del self.__list[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__list)

    def __contains__(self, value):
        """value in self"""
        return value in self.__list

    def __iadd__(self, value):
        """self += page || window"""
        if value.__class__ is Page or value.__class__ is Window:
            self.__list.append(value)
            # this line is required
            return self
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def __isub__(self, value):
        """self -= page || window"""
        while value in self.__list:
            self.__list.remove(value)
        # this line may be required
        return self

    def size(self, height=None, width=None):
        """This needs to be divided into two functions."""
        if height or width:
            if height:
                self.__assert_type((int, height))
                self.__height = height
            if width:
                self.__assert_type((int, width))
                self.__width = width
            return self
        return self.__height, self.__width

    def option(self, border=None, background=None):
        """This needs to be divided into two functions."""
        if border is not None or background is not None:
            if border is not None:
                self.__assert_type((str, border))
                if border:
                    self.__border = border[0]
                else:
                    self.__border = border
            if background is not None:
                self.__assert_type((str, background))
                if background:
                    self.__background = background[0]
                else:
                    self.__background = background
            return self
        return self.__border, self.__background

    def visible(self, value=None):
        """Get or set visible."""
        return self.__page.visible(value)

    def x(self, value=None):
        """Get or set x."""
        return self.__page.x(value)

    def y(self, value=None):
        """Get or set y."""
        return self.__page.y(value)

    def page(self):
        """This is like a casting statement."""
        self.__refresh()
        return self.__page

    def __refresh(self):
        temp = Page(self.__height, self.__width, self.__background) \
            .visible(self.__page.visible()).x(self.__page.x()).y(
            self.__page.y())
        self.__page = temp
        # Display Pages And Windows
        for item in self.__list:
            if item.visible():
                self.__page.project(item.page())
        # Create Borders
        if self.__border:
            self.__page.set_row(0, self.__border).set_row(self.__height - 1,
                                                          self.__border) \
                .set_column(0, self.__border).set_column(self.__width - 1,
                                                         self.__border)

    @staticmethod
    def __assert_type(*tuples):
        for types, objects in tuples:
            if type(objects) is not types:
                raise TypeError


def test_paw():
    it = Window(10, 10)
    print(it)
    print(it.option('#'))
    print(it.option(background='-'))
    it += Page(1, 1, '%').x(2).y(2)
    print(it)
    other = Page(2, 2, 'H')
    it += other.x(3).y(3)
    print(it)
    it -= other
    print(it)
    del it[0]
    print(it)
    other = Page(2, 2, '%')
    it += other.x(2).y(2)
    print(it)
    other_2 = Page(0, 0)
    it += other_2.y(5).x(2).link(other)
    print(it)
    other_2.mutate(0, 0, 'H')
    print(it)
    print(it.option('', ''))


card_0 = Page(5, 5)
card_0.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 0 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_1 = Page(5, 5)
card_1.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 1 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_2 = Page(5, 5)
card_2.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 2 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_3 = Page(5, 5)
card_3.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 3 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_4 = Page(5, 5)
card_4.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 4 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_5 = Page(5, 5)
card_5.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 5 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_6 = Page(5, 5)
card_6.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 6 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_7 = Page(5, 5)
card_7.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 7 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_8 = Page(5, 5)
card_8.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 8 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_9 = Page(5, 5)
card_9.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| 9 |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_10 = Page(5, 5)
card_10.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '|1 0|') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_A = Page(5, 5)
card_A.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| A |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_J = Page(5, 5)
card_J.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| J |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_Q = Page(5, 5)
card_Q.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| Q |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

card_K = Page(5, 5)
card_K.mutate(0, 0, '+---+') \
    .mutate(1, 0, '|   |').mutate(2, 0, '| K |') \
    .mutate(3, 0, '|   |').mutate(4, 0, '+---+')

CARD_LIST = [card_0, card_1, card_2, card_3, card_4, card_5, card_6, card_7,
             card_8, card_9]


def main():
    print('Welcome to WAR V5!\n')
    players = get_players()
    print()
    longest_name, names = get_names(players)
    deck = create_deck(players)
    hands = create_hands(deck, players)
    play_game_rounds(hands, longest_name, names, players)
    print('\n' * 50)
    display_scores(hands, names, players)
    for index in range(10):
        input(f'\nGAME OVER ... {9 - index}')


def display_scores(hands, names, players):
    for player_index, numeric_score in calculate_scores(hands, players):
        print(names[player_index], 'received', numeric_score, 'points.')


Score = collections.namedtuple('Score', 'player_index, numeric_score')


def calculate_scores(hands, players):
    scores = []
    for player in range(players):
        total = sum(hands[player].captured)
        scores.append(Score(player, total))
    scores.sort(key=lambda score: score.numeric_score)
    return scores


def play_game_rounds(hands, longest_name, names, players):
    for game_round in range(1, 11):
        table = []
        will_play = list(range(players))
        for turn in range(players):
            print('\n' * 50)
            play_one_person(game_round, hands, longest_name, names, table,
                            will_play)
        print('\n' * 50)
        show_pot(longest_name, names, table)
        distribute_pot(hands, table)
        summarize_captures(names, hands)
        input(f'\nEnd of Round {game_round}')


def show_pot(longest_name, names, table):
    table_window = Window(len(table) * 6, longest_name + 13)
    for index, (player_index, card) in enumerate(table):
        table_window += Page(1, len(names[player_index]) + 9) \
            .mutate(0, 0, names[player_index] + ' played') \
            .y(index * 6)
        table_window += Page(0, 0) \
            .link(CARD_LIST[card]) \
            .x(len(names[player_index]) + 8) \
            .y(index * 6)
    print(table_window)


def summarize_captures(names, hands):
    for index, hand in enumerate(hands):
        if hand.captured:
            print(names[index], 'has captured', len(hand.captured), 'cards.')


def distribute_pot(hands, table):
    high_card = max(item.card for item in table)
    hand_out = [player for player, card in table if card == high_card]
    while table:
        hands[random.choice(hand_out)].captured.append(table.pop(0).card)


def play_one_person(game_round, hands, longest_name, names, table,
                    will_play):
    now_play = will_play.pop(random.randrange(len(will_play)))
    print('Round', game_round)
    input(f"It is {names[now_play]}'s turn to play.\n")
    show_pot_before_play(longest_name, names, table)
    show_playing_cards(hands, now_play)
    show_captured_cards(hands, now_play)
    get_card_to_play(hands, now_play, table)


TableItem = collections.namedtuple('TableItem', 'player_index, card')


def get_card_to_play(hands, now_play, table):
    while True:
        try:
            card = int(input('What card do you want to play? '))
            if 0 <= card <= 9:
                try:
                    hands[now_play].playable.remove(card)
                except ValueError:
                    print('You do not have that card.')
                else:
                    table.append(TableItem(now_play, card))
                    break
            else:
                print('You must enter a value between 0 and 9.')
        except ValueError:
            print('You must enter a number.')


def show_captured_cards(hands, now_play):
    if hands[now_play].captured:
        hands[now_play].captured.sort()
        print('These are your captured cards:')
        capture_window = Window(7, len(hands[now_play].captured) * 6)
        for index, card in enumerate(hands[now_play].captured):
            capture_window += Page(0, 0) \
                .link(CARD_LIST[card]) \
                .x(index * 6 + 1) \
                .y(1)
        print(capture_window)


def show_playing_cards(hands, now_play):
    print('These are your playing cards:')
    playing_window = Window(7, len(hands[now_play].playable) * 6)
    for index, card in enumerate(hands[now_play].playable):
        playing_window += Page(0, 0) \
            .link(CARD_LIST[card]) \
            .x(index * 6 + 1) \
            .y(1)
    print(playing_window)


def show_pot_before_play(longest_name, names, table):
    if table:
        table_window = Window(len(table) * 6, longest_name + 13)
        for index, item in enumerate(table):
            table_window += Page(1, len(names[item.player_index]) + 9) \
                .mutate(0, 0, names[item.player_index] + ' played') \
                .y(index * 6)
            table_window += Page(0, 0) \
                .link(CARD_LIST[item.card]) \
                .x(len(names[item.player_index]) + 8) \
                .y(index * 6)
        print(table_window)
    else:
        print('There are no cards on the table.\n')


Hand = collections.namedtuple('Hand', 'playable, captured')


def create_hands(deck, players):
    hands = []
    random.seed()
    for player in range(players):
        hand = Hand([], [])
        for card in range(10):
            index = random.randrange(len(deck))
            hand.playable.append(deck.pop(index))
            hand.playable.sort()
        hands.append(hand)
    return hands


def create_deck(players):
    return [card for card in range(10) for _ in range(players)]


def get_names(players):
    names = [input(f'What is the name of player {name + 1}? ')
             for name in range(players)]
    return max(map(len, names)), names


def get_players():
    while True:
        try:
            players = int(input('How many players are there? '))
            if players > 1:
                return players
            print('There must be at least two players.')
        except ValueError:
            print('You must enter a number.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```